# TouchEvents for Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, ios, flex4, touch, flash-builder

I have successfully made my first application and imported it into my iPhone, but I can't seem to get TouchEvents to work. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code that I have currently:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

    public class TestIos extends Sprite
    {
        private var boll:Sprite = new Sprite;
        private var radius:Number = 40;

        public function TestIos()
        {
            super();

            // support autoOrients
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            this.addChild(boll);

            this.drawBoll();

            // Add events
            boll.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,onTouchBegin);
            boll.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,onTouchTap);
        }

        private function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void {
            var g:Graphics = boll.graphics;
            g.clear();
            g.beginFill(0xcc66cc,1);
            g.drawCircle(150,radius,radius);

            boll.scaleX = boll.scaleY = 1.25;

            boll.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,onTouchEnds);
            boll.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,onTouchMove);
        }

        private function onTouchMove(e:TouchEvent):void {
            boll.x = e.stageX;
            boll.y = e.stageY;
        }

        private function onTouchTap(e:TouchEvent):void {
            var g:Graphics = boll.graphics;
            g.clear();
            g.beginFill(0x33cc33,1);
            g.drawCircle(150,radius,radius);

            boll.scaleX = boll.scaleY = 1;
        }

        private function onTouchEnds(e:TouchEvent):void {
            this.drawBoll();

            boll.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,onTouchMove);
            boll.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,onTouchEnds);
        }

        private function drawBoll():void {
            var g:Graphics = boll.graphics;
            g.clear();
            g.beginFill(0x3399cc,1);
            g.drawCircle(150,radius,radius);

            boll.scaleX = boll.scaleY = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [look at the API and examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary).  In this case, it seems you're missing the `Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;` declaration.

Comment: Nothing happens differently when defining Multitouch.inputMode. is there a way of debuging touch events on the computer without the use of a touch device?

Comment: Please refer to the example.  Try using the example line for line to see if it works, then figure out what's missing in your code.